# Subscribing to ECBOT bonds

Tags: c#, interactive-brokers

I am using the C# Interactive Brokers API. I am successfully subscribing to ES, several currencies, stocks, etc. I need to subscribe to ZN and ZT quotes, but this doesn't seem to work as I get no callback or error message:

```
Contract zn = new Contract();
                zn.Currency = "USD";
                zn.Multiplier = "1000";
                zn.SecType = "FUT";
                zn.Symbol = "ZN";
                zn.LocalSymbol = "ZNZ5";
                zn.Exchange = "ECBOT";
                zn.PrimaryExch = "ECBOT";

Subscribe(zn);
```

I also tried

```
Contract zn = new Contract();
                zn.Currency = "USD";
                zn.Multiplier = "2000";
                zn.SecType = "FUT";
                zn.Symbol = "ZT";
                zn.LocalSymbol = "201512";
                zn.Exchange = "SMART";
                zn.PrimaryExch = "SMART";
```

And

```
Contract zn = new Contract();
                zn.Currency = "USD";
                zn.Multiplier = "1000";
                zn.SecType = "FUT";
                zn.Symbol = "ZN";
                zn.LocalSymbol = "ZN   DEC 15";
                zn.Exchange = "SMART";
                zn.PrimaryExch = "SMART";
```

I tried both one space after ZN and three spaces after `zn.LocalSymbol`, as I read that was the correct way.

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend using [Object Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx), as a side note, regardless of the api.

Comment: I think you're missing the most important parameter: `ConId`.

Comment: They're all wrong.  I'll update my answer.  And don't specify conid which you usually get by specifying the contract parameters properly in the first place.  Use the fewest fields possible, then if IB needs more info it will say so, instead of the no security def found error.

Comment: Is your account allowed to receive ZN/ZT quotes? Are you monitoring `EWrapper.error()` API (3 overloads) for any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `ZT` and `ZN` futures, you have to specify `ECBOT`, cannot use `SMART`. The field I was missing was

```
zt.LastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20151231";
```

You have to see the exact date. You can get it from the TWS itself by right clicking on the symbol and viewing the Contract Info.

Also, if I enter a `LocalSymbol` for this contract, it seems to break it.

Comment: If you're using the beta version, read the release notes.  https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5061&ns=T&nhf=T   This is explained there.  You don't need the 31 according to that.

Comment: Thanks will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Specify expiry and **not** the local symbol (a string "201512").  You're supposed to use one or the other, you're using symbol and local symbol.  I've never used local symbol and I think it might be "ZN DEC 15" anyway.

Also, you don't use primaryExchange here, that's for SMART routing ambiguity.  You should just set exchange to ECBOT.

For ZN the minimum info should be

```
Contract zn = new Contract();
            zn.Currency = "USD";//probably not even needed
            zn.SecType = "FUT";
            zn.Symbol = "ZN";
            zn.Expiry = "201512;
            zn.Exchange = "ECBOT";
```

You can try the java api sample, I don't think there is a C# sample.  Try and request data using that to see what works.

I just noticed you say there's no error message.  There should be one so make sure you're getting error callbacks from the API.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all of your suggestions to no success.

Comment: One thing I am not sure about, I think IB has to send a quuote before I get a callback, so it may be that I am not being patient enough and need to wait until a quote change happens. Still, I don't know what is correct to wait for.

Comment: You'll get something right away, maybe not a price tick, but day volume etc.  ZN will have plenty of ticks almost any time the market is open.

Comment: There is no such field Expiry. At least not in the C# version.

Comment: There is in the docs.  https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/csharp/contract.htm   Note there's a missing close quote in my example on expiry.

Comment: Sorry my bad. However, I think expiry here has to do with Options, not futures. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes I use it for futures but in java.  It should be the same in c#.

Comment: Thanks I was able to work it out and I posted my own answer. It was not intuitive at all.